# Replace loaded JavaScript with newly loaded one in head

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have web page which loads the JavaScript on when below function get called:

```
loadjavascript:function(v_url) 
    {
        if (v_url != indef && v_url != ' ') {
        
            var filename = '../includes/javascript.php?url=' + v_url;
        
            var fileref=document.createElement('script');
                fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
                fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);
            if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
                document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
        }   
    }
```

When I check in Firebug I can see so many same JavaScripts loaded in.

To resolve this issue what I want to do is -

1. When the function get called if JavaScript is not loaded then load it and append to head.
2. If function is called and it is same JavaScript which is already present in the head section then don't load the new one **but to run the already present JavaScript**.

Can it be done or it is not possible in JavaScript? Could anyone please share some ideas how to do it?

Comment: If a script is present in the head it should've already run. Why would you want to re-invoke a script that has already run?

Comment: @JacobDalton thank for reply.. i want to rerun it to perform some actions again on the loaded page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem suggests the need for refactoring. But answering the actual question asked: :-)

> 1) When the function get called if javascript is not loaded then load it and append to head.

This part is straight-forward, just loop through the existing `script` elements in `head`:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var list = head.getElementsByTagName('script');
var index, script, found;

found = false;
for (index = 0; !found && index < list.length; ++index) {
    script = list[index];
    if (script.src.indexOf('?url=' + v_url) !== -1) { // Or however precise you want to be
        found = true;
    }
}
if (found) {
    // It was found, don't load it again
}
else {
    // It wasn't found, load it
}
```

> 2) If function is called and it is same javascript which is already present in the head section then dont load the new one but to run the already present javascript.

This part requires changes to the script in question. Basically, if the script looks like this:

```
function defineSomeFunction() {
    // ...
}
function defineSomeOtherFunction() {
    // ...
}
if (foo) {
    bar();
}
if (thisCondition) {
    thatAction();
}
// etc.
```

...it needs to be modified such that all of the *inline* things it's doing (the two `if` statements above) are actually done by a function, like this:

```
function defineSomeFunction() {
    // ...
}
function defineSomeOtherFunction() {
    // ...
}
function inlineStuff() {
    if (foo) {
        bar();
    }
    if (thisCondition) {
        thatAction();
    }
    // etc.
}
inlineStuff();
```

Then, when you detect that it's already been loaded once, instead of loading it again, just call the `inlineStuff` function.

If you have more than one of these (and it looks like you do), you'll need to make sure the `inlineStuff` function names are unique and can be inferred or defined by the `v_url`, so you know what function to call. Then you can call it by referencing it on `window`, since that's where all globals go.

```
var functionName = figureOutFunctionNameFromURL(v_url);
window[functionName]();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you valuable response...

I am sorry i am able to use first part of your answer...just would like to check with you I may sound stupid..but in case script is found...(if (found) {
    // It was found, don't load it again) in that case can i remove it from head and append the new script.. so that the head section will be always clean and will have required scripts only...Thank you very much for your answer in advance..

Comment: @monamona: Removing a `script` element from the DOM does nothing to remove the code it loaded from the JavaScript execution environment associated with the window. So usually it's best to leave it there as a marker so you know that that code has been loaded. To actually remove code from the JavaScript environment, the code has to be designed to be unloadable (which can be straight-forward in some cases [if the code set no event handlers or anything], or non-trivial [if it does]).

Comment: Hi T.J sorry to say that after so many tries i am not able to get it running..

for (index = 0; !found && index < list.length; ++index) {
      script = list[index];
      if (script.src.indexOf('?url=' + v_url) !== -1) { // Or however precise you want to be
          found = true;
      }
  } i am never getting script found even script is present.. any idea.. i think something is missing..

Comment: @monamona: There must be some other problem with your code, fundamentally the above works. [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ubejil/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ubejil/1/edit)

Comment: Yes.. T.J. i can see it is running..exactly i want in this example...let me see...may be i am missing something somewhere..thank you very much...

Comment: Yes.. it worked like charm.. it was my fault... very silly mistake...i am sorry for bothering and doubting your code.. thank you very much.. T.J.

Comment: @monamona: Oh, doubt away! We all make mistakes. :-) Glad that's working for you now!